# Authorization for applications hosted in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a WebAPI and MVC application hosted in AWS EC2 instance. It should not be publicly accessible and it cannot be restricted by IP address.

Is there any built-in mechanism in AWS that can be used to authorize all the requests to the applications hosted in EC2 instance? Like creating the signature and passing it in the query string or headers..

Thanks All...

Comment: Did you take a look at the Amazon's IAMS service? It sounds like this is exactly what you need. In a nutshell, you create an many app accounts / profiles as are required, and for each create a tailored policy. From memory you then apply those policies to each Amazon service you're trying to secure e.g. S3 buckets, EC2 instances etc

Comment: Thanks theruss for ur immediate reply.                                                        I tried looking into that. Using IAM service i am able to authorize the EC2 api requests(create and modify EC2 resource). But I am looking for the authorization of applications(MVC and webapi) hosted in EC2 using any inbuilt mechanism.

Comment: Sorry I can't help any further then. There is a dedicated SO site for hosting / infrasructure but I don't recall the title off the top of my head. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For authorization between client and a server in EC2, you can use Cognito from AWS to enable JWT based authorization.

Cognito has javascript APIs (via amplify) that support operations like signup, reset password, account verification, login, and token generation. Then you can incorporate JWT token validation into your EC2 endpoints